# Scala array iteration unformated output

Tags: scala

Here  array values are iterate using Iterator and print one by one.

or [My language is not good]

i want to print array values one by one using iteration

```
package com.aitrich.collection

object IteratorDemo {
def main(args: Array[String]) {

      var myList = Array("a", "number", "of", "words")  

      var l=myList.length

      for( i <- 0 to l){
      var Lst:String=myList.toString()
      val it = Iterator(l.formatted(Lst))
      while (it.hasNext){
         println(it.next())
      }
      }

   }
}
```

but the **output** shows

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@aad33f6
[Ljava.lang.String;@aad33f6
[Ljava.lang.String;@aad33f6
[Ljava.lang.String;@aad33f6
[Ljava.lang.String;@aad33f6
```

Comment: `myList foreach println`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Scala it is more idiomatic to avoid using index to work on collections:

```
val myList = Array("a", "number", "of", "words") 
myList.foreach(s => println(s))
```

Note that `Iterator(a)` creates an iterator with a single element `a` in it.

If you want to prefix with the index of the element:

```
myList.zipWithIndex.foreach{ case (s, i) => println(s"$i: $s")}

// 0: a
// 1: number
// 2: of
// 3: words
```

Comment: thnx.. alot..               .

Comment: @Mila, By the way I was looking at your other question and you seem to be having difficulties with dealing with arrays. When you see something like this `[Ljava.lang.String;@aad33f6`, it means you are printing an array, not its element. Arrays are indexed at 0, and to access the first element of array `myList` you can do `myList(0)`. To access the ith element, `myList(i)`.